# 'Undefined reference to' error in C++ although function definition exists in header file in include path

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, include-path, unresolved-external

Please bear with me if this is a naive question. I tried to see if this was answered elsewhere on SO, but I didn't quite find a question that answered this.

I see an error when I try to compile some C++ code (test.cpp). I am including some headers, as follows -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "lefrReader.hpp"
```

lefrReader.hpp has the definition of function lefrInit(), and is present in the folder /foo/bar/include, say.

I am compiling this code with the following (in a UNIX environment) -

```
g++ -I/foo/bar/include -L/foo/bar/include ./test.cpp -o ./test
```

However, this fails with this error -

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `lefrInit()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Shouldn't having the /foo/bar/include directory in the include (-I) path help with finding lefrReader.hpp?

EDIT - I also tried the following to no avail (from [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400)) -

```
g++ -I/foo/bar/include -L/foo/bar/include ./test.cpp -o ./test -llefrReader
```

Error -

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `lefrInit()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I't not complaining that it cant find a .hpp, it's complaining about the function definition.

Comment: -I is used for compilation.  Not linking.

Comment: The linker doesn't care at all about header files.  Functions are merely declared in header files, not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to link with `lefrReader.o`.

Comment: @Barmar, I previously went through all the scenarios in the question you linked, and did not find any that matched my question.

If you think it is a duplicate, do you mind pointing to which answer to the other question helps me, please?

Comment: This answer [Failure to link against appropriate libraries/object files or compile implementation files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1491895)

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. I tried that out, and it did not work for me either. I added an edit to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` is for linking with libraries, so `-llefRreader` looks for `lefrReader.a` (static library) or `lefrReader.so` (shared library).

To link with a single object file, you just put the object file as an argument.

```
g++ -I/foo/bar/include ./test.cpp /foo/bar/include/lefrReader.o -o ./test
```

You have to previously compile that file:

```
g++ -I/foo/bar/include lefrReader.cpp -c -o lefrReader.o
```

Or you can compile and link them both at once:

```
g++ -I/foo/bar/include ./test.cpp /foo/bar/include/lefrReader.cpp -o ./test
```

However, this means you'll recompile both `.cpp` files even when just one of them has changed. When you start working with multiple files, it's a good time to start using a `makefile`, which can automate all the dependencies.